# 'Schema class name does not revalidate' error when trying to add a class to parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to save a class to parse. However, when I do that it gives me the error 'schema class name does not revalidate'. How do I handle this?

I've already tried to change the name of the class, but even then it does not work. I'm a beginner when it comes to parse.

```
let myPost = PFObject(className: textField.text!)
            myPost["Name"] = textField.text!
            myPost["Notes"] = Note.text
            myPost["memberNumber"] = Int(stepper.value)
            myPost["members"] = "\((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!):\((Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)!)'"
            myPost.saveInBackground { (successful, error) in
                if successful {
                   NSLog("Event Saved")
                }
                else {
                    NSLog("Save failed")
                    print(error)
                }
```

It should save, but it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: What is the class name?

Comment: Is allowClientClassCreation flag set to true in your Parse Server?

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue has to do with your class name i had the same error the class name should  be in a string without space  or any other symbols i.e "Username" not "User name" or "user name ?"

i hope this helps.